How to resolve problems with DNS when a DNS server is configured
DNS SERVIDOR NETWORKING
Soluction a problem reportI have some servers (3 servers) that are having trouble resolving site names (DNS). The solution I found was to set the machines to use 8.8.8.8 directly to resolve names since the 3 servers are not resolving.
The servers have already been restarted, but the browsing slowness continues, even though the internet links are operational.
However, the DNS resolution by the servers is not functional. Some suggestions I found were to restart the servers, which has already been done.
